# Iterating through lists in a string by it's name while adding it to another list?

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop

Ok, I hope my question is clear enough, however, I will show you the code I'm trying to create to better explain myself.
I have multiple lists:

```
char[] alphabet = { 'A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' };
List<String> A = new List<String>();
List<String> B = new List<String>();
List<String> C = new List<String>();
List<String> list = new List<String>(); 
file.WriteLine("<div id=\"multiColumn\"><ul>");
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
{
    list.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, A)+"<br/><ul><li><a class=\"anchor\" id=\"" + alphabet[i] + "\"></a>" + "<strong>" + alphabet[i] + "</strong><a/></li></ul>");
}
```

In my code, I'm trying to create a dynamic way of iterating through my lists(A,B,C) based off of which position it is in the alphabet[i].

I've tried doing things like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
 {
     list.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, alphabet[i])+"<br/><ul><li><a class=\"anchor\" id=\"" + alphabet[i] + "\"></a>" + "<strong>" + alphabet[i] + "</strong><a/></li></ul>");
 }
```

Any suggestions or help would be great. I've looked around, but haven't found anything quite like what I need. Perhaps I'm searching the wrong terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `alphabet` is in order and `'A'`is at index 0 the List A,B,C could be added to a `List<List<string>>` (in order of course). or maybe a `Dictionary<char,List<string>>`

so that :

```
alphabet[i] =='A'
alphaList[i] == A //the List<string> A
```

or

```
alphaDict[alphabet[i]] == A //the List<string> A
```

you know, what ever your coding style prefers. Lists and dictionaries have there strenghts and weaknesses so that should be considered for which one you use

Comment: This was perfect, thank you so much! I ended up using the List<List<string>>.